# Is it possible to share forms authentication *only* across sub-sub domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I know I can share forms authentication across 2 subdomains `sub1.domain.com`, `sub2.domain.com` by using the following Web.config setting:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms domain="domain.com" />
</authentication>
```

However, I have 2 "sub-sub" domains (not sure if there's a better term for that) `a.sub.domain.com`, and `b.sub.domain.com`. Now I want to share the forms authentication cookies *only* on `sub.domain.com`, and *not* my entire `domain.com`. Is it possible to do this?

I tried the obvious solution below but it doesn't work, and always redirects back to the login page:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms domain="sub.domain.com" />
</authentication>
```

Is it possible to share the cookies *only* across domains that end with `sub.domain.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turned out that my old cookies in my browser were somehow conflicting with the new setting.

After clearing all `domain.com` cookies, the solution I was trying now works, in case anyone faces a similar situation.

Also note I believe it's preferable to prepend a `.` to the domain:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms domain=".sub.domain.com" />
</authentication>
```