# Forms Authentication Shared Across Websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, forms-authentication

I'm developing a mobile-only sub domain website for an existing website. (The main site is www.domain.com and the mobile-only site I'm developing is m.domain.com.)

When a user logs into the main website, I want to redirect them to the mobile-only website if:

1. They appear to be on a mobile device
2. They have a particular role

When redirected, they should not have to log in a second time. And so I want to share authentication across websites. The main website uses Forms Authentication.

I am trying to follow the steps described in the article [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx). The main thing is that you must "set attributes of the forms and `machineKey` sections of the *Web.config* file to the same values for all applications that are participating in shared forms authentication."

I have done this. However, it's still not working. I can log in or out of either site using the same credentials. But logging in or out of one site does not have any effect on the login status of the other.

The article has this note:

> Applications that run ASP.NET version 2.0 or later can share forms authentication ticket information with earlier versions of ASP.NET if you include decryption="3DES" in the machineKey element for each ASP.NET version 2.0 (or later) application.

This does not seem to apply.

Also, I do not specify the `domain` attribute of the `authentication` element. It says it's optional, and that the default value will be "".

Can anyone suggestion what else I might try. I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net forms authentication and multiple domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056686/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-multiple-domains)

Comment: @NightOwl888: That's not the same. That question is about two domains that reference the *same website*. I have two domains that reference different websites.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question that specifies you are using multiple domains. You only say different websites (which could be on the same subdomain).

Comment: As per my first sentence, it's a "mobile-only subdomain". I can see any possible situation where that would use the exact same domain as the main website. I can give you a hundred reasons why ever having a two websites with the same domain sounds like a bad idea. But it has been ruled out when one is a *subdomain* of the other.

Comment: Ok, then this stands as a duplicate of the above link. The fact that you have 2 different websites and the asker of the question has 1 makes no difference in regards to the answer given. The limiting factor is that of cookies, which is possible to do on multiple subdomains if you follow those instructions. But you definitely need to synchronize the machine keys: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, but I wonder if you read my question. I indicated the machine keys are the same.

Comment: Consider an emphasized update to your post based on described details in comments which are important things in your question to solve it as soon as possible my friend

Comment: The short answer is machine key. If an app can be reached through domain or sub-domain, Forms authentication will track it as same app (or SSO) as long as they share machine key. I would like to see your IIS config file and would like to know how you set the machine key. Did you use `AutoGenerate`?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich: I'm not familiar with `AutoGenerate`. But if that generates the key for you, then obviously I didn't use that as that would not allow me to ensure both machine keys are the same. Note that this is on a shared, cloud hosting account. So some aspects of how IIS is configured is out of my control.

Comment: which host do you use?

Comment: I'm on NewTek's cloud hosting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462755/is-it-possible-to-share-forms-authentication-only-across-sub-sub-domains

Comment: Try giving domain name not subdomain, make sure same authentication cookie is generated/used for both sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what is wrong.

> Also, I do not specify the domain attribute of the authentication
>   element. It says it's optional, and that the default value will be "".

You should set the domain attribute in the forms element like this(not sure about the dot indicating a subdomain).

```
<forms domain=".mydomain.com" loginUrl="member_login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

The CookieDomain property value is set in the configuration file for an ASP.NET application by using the domain attribute of the forms configuration element. The CookieDomain property value determines the Domain that the cookie will be used for.

The documentation from your link states that

> You can omit the domain attribute of the forms tag if there is only
>   one Web site on the server.

Which in your case, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to share within the same domain this shouldn't be a problem. machine key matters only if you are going to deal with multiple servers or domains.

In your case it's the same domain on the same server, therefore if you set the domain (there is a property in httpcookie) to be "domain.com" (you should not mention any subdomain) in your authentication cookie, I remember that this can be done in web.config (forms authentication section) itself, this should work for you.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="30" name=".FormAuth" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".domain.com" /> </authentication>
```

or if you are manually creating the cookie you could create a cooike like ,

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(); cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
```

This good post explains the same, which I found later....

[Asp.net forms authentication and multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056686/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-multiple-domains)

Comment: How would I tell forms authentication to set that property in its cookies?

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="30" name=".FormAuth" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"  domain=".domain.com" />
    </authentication>  or if you are manually creating the cookie you could create a cooike like , var cookie = new HttpCookie(); cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";

Comment: just noticed this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056686/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-multiple-domains

Comment: Please update your answer instead of expanding on your answer in a comment.